# How to avoid conflicts between dnsmasq and systemd-resolved?

Tags: systemd, dnsmasq

I recently installed [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) to act as DNS Server for my local network. dnsmasq listens on port 53 which is already in use by the local DNS stub listener from [systemd-resolved](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html).

Just stopping systemd-resolved and then restart it after dnsmasq is running solves this issue. But it returns after a reboot: systemd-resolved is started with preference and dnsmasq will not start because port 53 is already in use.

The first obvious question, I guess, is how do I best make systemd-resolved understand that it should not start the local DNS stub listener and thus keep port 53 for use by dnsmasq?

A more interesting question, however, is how the two services are generally meant to work together. Are they even meant to work side by side or is systemd-resolved just in the way if one's using dnsmasq?

Comment: Have you tried just disabling via `sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved`? dnsmasq if properly configured should handle the domain resolution I think.

Comment: You also have to issue `sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved` if it is running. Use  `sudo systemctl status systemd-resolved` to check

Answer (score 91, accepted):

As of [systemd 232](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v232/NEWS#L272-L275) (released in 2017) you can edit `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` (not `/etc/resolv.conf`) and add this line:

```
DNSStubListener=no
```

This will switch off binding to port 53. Make sure that the file has the `[Resolve]` section header on top (which should be the case unless the installation is broken).

The option is described in more details in the [`resolved.conf` manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/resolved.conf.html).

You can find the systemd version your system is running with:

```
systemctl --version
```

Comment: Doing this turn of the internet connection

Comment: @Ravinder: It will disable the systemd DNS server, yes.  If your system is configured to use this server then it will look like the Internet connection stops working (because you turned it off).  You will need to configure your system to use another DNS server instead.  Typically people turn off binding on port 53 because they want to run their own DNS server there instead, so it's not a problem.

Comment: I added `DNSStubListener=no` in the `/etc/resolve.conf`  still I was not able to ping , then I changed nameserver to router ip in resolve.conf and it was all working

Comment: also `chmod 0444 /etc/resolv.conf` and just documenting the link here https://askubuntu.com/questions/973017/wrong-nameserver-set-by-resolvconf-and-networkmanager?rq=1

Comment: setting `DNSStubListener=no` will cause internet to not work so I think it is useful to set the DNS server IP in /etc/dhcpcd.conf on the eth0 interface i.e. set `static domain_name_server=127.0.0.53 1.1.1.1` restart dhcpcd and dnsmasq service.

Comment: @ChangZhao It doesn't cause the Internet to stop working, but if your system is configured to send queries to the DNSStubListener and you then turn it off then of course DNS queries aren't going to work.  If you haven't already configured your system to query some other service for DNS then there's no need to mess around with the `DNSStubListener` option and you should leave it at the default. If you turn it off and your Internet breaks then it means you aren't running another DNS server on your local machine (like `bind` or `dnsmasq`) so you shouldn't be changing the `DNSStubListener` option.

Comment: Confused... this option appears to be completely pointless. How is this any better than simply disabling `systemd-resolved`?

Comment: @EML: Have a read of the [systemd-resolved manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html).  It explains that there are multiple ways programs interact with systemd-resolved, and responding to direct DNS request is a last-resort mechanism for supporting old programs that do not use the C APIs.  If you disable systemd-resolved then you lose all its functionality, but if you disable just the DNS resolver then the majority of programs on your system will be unaffected and will continue to use systemd-resolved and benefit from its enhanced features.

Comment: On a fresh Ubuntu 22.10 this has no effect. I had to add "[Resolve]" at the top of the config file (answer edited to reflect this).

Comment: @Damien: The file should already have that at the top, if not it is a bug in your Linux distribution or you mistakenly deleted the file at some point.

Answer (score 44):

I just enabled option "bind-interfaces" by removing '#' at the start of the line in /etc/dnsmasq.conf.

**I was able to start dnsmasq again:**

- dnsmasq bind DNS port on all interfaces (including 127.0.0.1) port 53,
- systemd-resolv keeps listening on 127.0.0.**53**:53

I was pointed to this solution by this discussion [resolved: add an option to disable the stub resolver](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/4061)

Comment: This is the best answer for what is a dumpster fire. There is no reason systemd should be occupying that port, even on loopback.

Comment: if there are still people looking into this issue, I TELL YOU, this WORKED like a charm and so far the best answer

Comment: +1. This solution worked on Fedora 33. I don't need to stop systemd-resolv. Port 53 is used by both.

Comment: Wow thanks it does not make any sense from the option name but it works!

Comment: Top answer! This is what I needed to run both resolved and dnsmasq at the same time.

Comment: this approach won't work if you want the local dns work for its own system. `dig xxx` will fail but `dig @127.0.0.1 xxx` can work, if `xxx` resolved by dnsmasq. Because the `/etc/resolv.conf` is still using 127.0.0.53 and resolved listens on `127.0.0.53`. One need to use the accepted answer to not allow resolved listen on that address.

Comment: This is a good answer to explain the root cause of the issue. So you just need to start either of them and also make sure you query from the listening address/port.

Answer (score 30):

You can disable `systemd-resolved` from loading at boot using `sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved`.

If you want to run the two together, you can redirect the `systemd-resolved` to use the localhost as the primary nameserver. This will make sure that all queries are directed to dnsmasq for resolution before hitting the external DNS server. This can be done by adding the line `nameserver 127.0.0.1` at the top of your `/etc/resolv.conf` file. This will also disable systemd's local caching.

You can read more on the [Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/dnsmasq#DNS_addresses_file). I copied this from there and it covers it quite well.

However this does not reliably avoid the error at boot time, i.e. dnsmasq will still fail if systemd-resolved happens to start first.  If your version of `systemd` is new enough, use the answer by [Malvineous](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/6662/malvineous).  If your version of `systemd` is too old, you can work around this problem by modifying the dnsmasq unit: in the `[Unit]` section, add `Before=systemd-resolved` .

After this, if you like, you can create a separate `/etc/dnsmasq-resolv.conf` file for the upstream nameservers and pass it using the `-r` or `--resolv-file` option, or add the upstream nameservers to the dnsmasq configuration file and use the `-R` or `--no-resolv` option. This way you only have the localhost in your `/etc/resolv.conf` and everything goes through dnsmasq.

Comment: I had to remove my previous comment as I can no longer confirm that this solved the issue. I did read the wiki before asking here, and I already had a resolv.conf file with the localhost nameserver at the top. This didn't help. I then followed your instructions to move out the external nameservers to a second file for dnsmasq. After the first reboot, dnsmasq loaded first so the problem didn't arise. At the second reboot, resolved loaded first so dnsmasq exited with the described error. I'm as far as before.

Comment: In the dnsmasq unit, put a `Before=systemd-resolved` in the `[Unit]` section. That way, dnsmasq will always start first.

Answer (score 15):

Here is solution for (X)Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic.

Install dnsmasq

```
sudo apt install dnsmasq
```

Disable systemd-resolved listener on port 53 (do not touch /etc/systemd/resolved.conf, because it may be overwritten on upgrade):

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/noresolved.conf 
[Resolve]
DNSStubListener=no
```

and restart it

```
$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```

(alternatively disable it completely by `$ sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved.service`
)

Delete /etc/resolv.conf and create again. This is important, because resolv.conf is a symbolic link to /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf by default. If you will not delete symbolic link, the file will be overwritten by systemd on reboot (even though we disabled systemd-resolved!). Also NetworkManager (NM) checks if it is a symbolic link to detect systemd-resolved configuration.

```
$ sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
$ sudo touch /etc/resolv.conf
```

Disable overwriting of /etc/resolv.conf by NM (there is also an option rc-manager, but it does not work, despite it is described in the NM manual):

```
$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/disableresolv.conf 
[main]
dns=none
```

and restart it:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Tell dnsmasq to use resolv.conf from NM:

```
$ cat /etc/dnsmasq.d/nmresolv.conf 
resolv-file=/var/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf
```

and restart it:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq
```

Use dnsmasq for resolving:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Use local dnsmasq for resolving
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: After trying a few other solutions, yours was the one that solved my problem on Linux Mint 19.1. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Been trying to fix this for days and this seemed pretty promising at first but alas, still getting `Feb 14 11:35:32 ip-172-31-27-116 dnsmasq[9181]: failed to create listening socket for 127.0.0.1: Address already in use`

Comment: You must have something else listening on port 53.  Try  
    sudo netstat -ltpn | grep -w 53

Comment: Another dnsmasq instance may be started for example by a container management software. Then you need another approach to configure dnsmasq.

Answer (score 10):

Judging from the systemd manpages it's not intended being able to manually disable the stub DNS server. Interestingly I only noticed the described problem after upgrading systemd from 230 to 231.

Disabling systemd-resolved was no option for me because I need it to handle received upstream DNS servers through DHCP.

My solution was making dnsmasq stop systemd-resolved before starting and starting it afterwards again.

I created a drop-in config in `/etc/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service.d/resolved-fix.conf`:

```
[Unit]
After=systemd-resolved.service

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/systemctl stop systemd-resolved.service
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/systemctl start systemd-resolved.service
```

This appears to be a rather hackish solution but it works.

Comment: Hey actually this solution is pretty slick. It is persistent even after package updates because it keeps the original unit file. Nicely done. The following is stated under `DNSStubListener` in the resolved.conf manual: "Note that the DNS stub listener is turned off implicitly when its listening address and port are already in use." That is why this method works fine I think.

Comment: A++ solution!!!

Comment: I had to change /usr/bin/systemctl to /bin/systemctl

Answer (score 4):

There will be an option in `systemd` version `232` to disable the stub listener. See https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/4061.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why both services are trying to use the same address. Maybe you can arrange them as in my case on Xubuntu 18.04.1, where their configuration is the following:

```
xy@zq:~$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 53
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13549/systemd-resol 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9632/dnsmasq
```

`systemd-resolved` works like this by default (it only listens on 127.0.0.53), but `dnsmasq` tries to bind the wildcard address by default. To allow them to work side-by-side as seen above, set the following dnsmasq options (either in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` or `/etc/dnsmasq.d/pick-your-own-filename.conf`):

```
listen-address=127.0.0.1
bind-interfaces
```

To make systemd-resolved using my dnsmasq I just set:

```
#/etc/systemd/resolved.conf 
[Resolve]
DNS=127.0.0.1
```

In my dnsmasq config I set my external nameservers:

```
#/etc/dnsmasq.conf
nameserver x.x.x.x
nameserver y.y.y.y
```

After restarting everything:

```
# sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service
# sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq.service
```

systemd-resolved will set the default DNS server to dnsmasq in:

```
#/etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: That last line surprised me, so I looked it up.  It sounds like in your case, `/etc/resolv.conf` is a symlink to `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`.  Apparently this is one of [four (!) possible different modes](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html#/etc/resolv.conf) that systemd-resolved could be operating in.  I guess it depends how your distribution set it up, i.e. it is true for your Xubuntu 18.04.1, but it might be different on other systems.

Comment: Been trying to fix this for days and this seemed like the only answer so far (out of dozens) with any home, however, after all that still getting `Feb 14 11:35:32 ip-172-31-27-116 dnsmasq[9181]: failed to create listening socket for 127.0.0.1: Address already in use`

Comment: Thanks, this was the direction I opted for for now in order to use `.local.test` domains. Requests to the systemd-resolved stub resolver (127.0.0.53) get delegated to dnsmasq at 127.0.0.1, which in turn falls back to external nameservers (e.g. google, cloudflare). *However!* The `nameserver` settings in `dnsmasq.conf` needed to be `server=x.x.x.x` `server=y.y.y.y` instead of the `resolv.conf` format. `dig` and `nslookup` don't need any special server arg to find my test domains.

Answer (score 4):

In my case (needing to provide a DNS service to other machines) I was able to solve the problem by telling dnsmasq to only bind to the ethernet interface (systemd-resolvd binds to loop-back) by setting....

```
...
interface=eth0
...
bind-interfaces
```

in dnsmasq.conf

Comment: I had to add `except-interface=lo` as well, to tell dnsmasq to avoid to bind on the loopback interface.

Comment: Using except-interfaces=lo is probably a much more sensible approach as it avoids issues with multiple NICs and/or device renaming.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a default Ubuntu 18.04 setup, this *may* be caused by a conflict between `systemd-resolved` (the default DNS server) and `dnsmasq`. If you installed `dnsmasq` yourself deliberately because you explicitly wanted it, then one of the other answers to this question, explaining how to disable `systemd-resolved`, will probably be good for you. If you *didn't* explicitly install `dnsmasq`, then it is likely in place because you're using `lxd`. This might be because you actually use `lxd` to manage containers, but it's most likely to be because snaps use `lxd` to protect you when apps are installed. From my perspective, I want to keep `dnsmasq` (because `lxd` wants it) but I also want to keep `systemd-resolved` as the DNS server (because it's what the Ubuntu team chose and I trust them more than myself).

So, this seems to be an `lxd` problem at heart. If so, the way I fixed it, as per [a lxd-users mailing list post](https://lists.linuxcontainers.org/pipermail/lxc-users/2017-April/013158.html), is this:

`$ lxc network edit lxdbr0`

This will edit your configuration in a terminal editor. It will look something like this:

```
config:
  ipv4.address: 10.216.134.1/24
  ipv4.nat: "true"
  ipv6.address: none
  ipv6.nat: "true"
name: lxdbr0
type: bridge
```

Add three lines to it:

```
config:
  ipv4.address: 10.216.134.1/24
  ipv4.nat: "true"
  ipv6.address: none
  ipv6.nat: "true"
  raw.dnsmasq: |
    auth-zone=lxd
    dns-loop-detect
name: lxdbr0
type: bridge
```

and this should cause `dnsmasq`, which is being run by `lxd`, to detect DNS loops. This, at least for me, solved the problem and stopped `systemd-resolved` and `dnsmasq` using 100% CPU.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it this way:

Add or uncomment the following line in ***/etc/default/dnsmasq***:

```
IGNORE_RESOLVCONF=yes
```

Create your own resolv file (/etc/resolv.personal) to define nameservers. You can use any nameserver here. I took two from https://www.opennic.org

```
nameserver 5.132.191.104
nameserver 103.236.162.119
```

In ***/etc/dnsmasq.conf*** add or uncomment the following line:

```
resolv-file=/etc/resolv.personal
```

Then restart dnsmasq and disable the default resolver: systemd-resolved.

```
sudo service dnsmasq restart

sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved
sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get dnsmasq to start using the solutions found online, i.e. disabling systemd-resolved, changing dnsmasq.conf to do "bind dynamic" instead of "bind interfaces". I was able to get it to start at boot by having dnsmasq start After network-online.service rather than network.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server
Requires=network.target
Wants=nss-lookup.target
Before=nss-lookup.target
After=network-online.target #This line changed
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the approach you are using. Note that normally when you order against network-online.target, you are also supposed to add network-online.target to the list of `Wants=`. https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me (after hours of pain) in Ubuntu 18.10 Cosmic Cuttlefish.  I did this to take advantage `dnsmasq`'s comparatively more robust caching mechanism and to avoid [NGINX resolver vulnerabilities](http://blog.zorinaq.com/nginx-resolver-vulns/). Note that I'm using the Ubuntu Server edition (no `NetworkManager`/`nmcli`, just `systemd-networkd`) and this is running on AWS EC2, so I also needed to keep DNS and DHCP working with the default EC2 search domain. I didn't want to disable `systemd-resolved` entirely because I have no idea how that might affect future updates.  Everything here is run as root/sudo unless otherwise noted (this happens by default when passed in as EC2 User Data).

```
## Configure dnsmasq to work with systemd-resolved
# Set static hostname with hostnamectl
hostnamectl set-hostname mydomainname
# Add an entry for the hostname to /etc/hosts
tee --append /etc/hosts <<EOF
127.0.0.1 mydomainname
EOF
# Disable stub listener for resolvconf and set DNS to loopback
tee --append /etc/systemd/resolved.conf <<EOF
DNSStubListener=no
DNS=127.0.0.1
EOF
# Tell dnsmasq to ignore resolvconf
tee --append /etc/default/dnsmasq <<EOF
IGNORE_RESOLVCONF=yes
EOF
# Create dropin directory
mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service.d
# Create systemd dropin to make sure systemd-resolved stops before dnsmasq starts
tee /etc/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service.d/resolved-fix.conf <<EOF
[Unit]
After=systemd-resolved.service
[Service]
ExecStartPre=bin/systemctl stop systemd-resolved.service
ExecStartPost=bin/systemctl start systemd-resolved.service
EOF
# Create custom resolvconf with name servers (I usec cloudflare)
tee /etc/resolv.mydomainname <<EOF
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.0.0.1 
nameserver [2606:4700:4700::1111] 
nameserver [2606:4700:4700::1001] 
EOF
# Configure dnsmasq
tee /etc/dnsmasq.d/mydomainname.conf <<EOF
# Region comes from:
# EC2_AVAIL_ZONE=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone)
# EC2_REGION=${EC2_AVAIL_ZONE%?}
domain=$EC2_REGION.compute.internal
resolv-file=/etc/resolv.mydomainname
listen-address=127.0.0.1
port=53
interface=lo
bind-dynamic
domain-needed
bogus-priv
dnssec
dns-forward-max=300
cache-size=1000
neg-ttl=3600
EOF
# Reload to pick up dropin
systemctl daemon-reload
# Stop systemd-resolved
systemctl stop systemd-resolved
# Start dnsmasq
systemctl restart dnsmasq
```

Verify that `127.0.0.1#53` is being used for resolution and DNSSEC is working with something like `dig +trace facebook.com`

Comment: Do you know why you still need this unit file dropin hack, when you have set `DNSStubListener=no` ?